# App Engine remote_api from one instance to another

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, remoteapi

I have an app engine app which create model objects and put them to another app. On dev_server this application work's great but when I upload the code to app engine I've got an error:

> from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
>
> > ImportError: cannot import name remote_api_stub

In the documentation is written that remote_api can be used to connect from dev_server to app instance and from one instance to another but I didn't find any explanation how can I do this.

Where is the remote_api_stub on app engine? Or in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi#Running_Remote_Shell) is bug?

> You can also use Remote API to access the datastore of one App Engine app from a different App Engine app.